# Java 8 Function defining in stream().map()

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> C` and I would like to use Stream to map it into a simple 2D array. My first step was mapping it into an ArrayList of int arrays and I came up with this:

```
this.C = C.stream().map(new Function<ArrayList<Integer>, int[]>(){
            public int[] apply(ArrayList<Integer> person) {
                return new int[0];
            }
        })
```

But it tells me that `map(Function<? super ArrayList<Integer>,? extends R>)` cannot be applied to my `Function<ArrayList<Integer>,int[]>`.
I can't figure out which of the parameters is the problem here and why.

Comment: You should be careful with these conversions because your arraylists inside arraylist can have different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 uses type inference. The types are determined by how the code is used.  The type of your expression has to be

```
Stream<int[]> c = ....
```

If your `this.C` is any other type, the type inference will get confused and assume the problem is in the first type it couldn't determine, rather than the type of the expression doesn't match the type you are assigning it to.

```
public static int[][] to2d(List<? extends List<Integer>> matrix) {
    return matrix.stream()
                  // convert each List<Integer> to an int[]
                  .map(a -> a.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray())
                  // convert the int[]s to an int[][]
                  .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I din't even notice that I tried to assign it back to C :D
Thanks for the example too.

Comment: It's the type inference which means the error message is not immediately related to where the mistake is.

Comment: Could you also by any chance explain why `int[] G = B.stream().map(Integer::intValue).toArray(int[]::new);` also causes a type inference issue at `int[]::new`? Where B is an `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: `.map(..)` returns an `Object` so your `.toArray()` must return an `Object[]` or a sub-class.  Most likely you intended to use `.mapToInt(i -> i)`

Comment: Yes, I was meaning to imitate `.mapToInt`, but in the example you gave you successfully used `.toArray(int[][]::new)`, is int[][] a subclass of Object[] and int[] isn't?

Comment: @seMikel yes `int[][]` is a subclass of `Object[]` but you are not using either. You are using a `Stream<Integer>` which needs to map to an `IntStream` to produce an `int[]`